# Sequential/ordinal random number generator

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I need it so the next number generated is greater than the last... this is my first project with object-oriented programming, so I don't know much. Also, how do I make it so it runs a certain number of simulations before it lands on a number grouping? It would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Randomize()

        TextBox1.Text = Rand(1, 100)
        TextBox2.Text = Rand(1, 100)
        TextBox3.Text = Rand(1, 100)
        TextBox4.Text = Rand(1, 100)
        TextBox5.Text = Rand(1, 100)
        TextBox6.Text = Rand(1, 100)
        TextBox7.Text = Rand(1, 100)
        TextBox8.Text = Rand(1, 200)

    End Sub
    Public Function Rand(ByVal Low As Long, ByVal High As Long) As Long
        Rand = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd()) + Low
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: There are many ways to create a series of numbers.  But it is hard to understand what you are after.  Sequential and Ordinal are pretty much mutually exclusive to Random

Comment: If you want the next number to be greater than the previous....  how many numbers is the generator going to produce before it breaks? It sounds like what you want is to generate a sequence of random numbers _and then sort them_ so that each is greater than the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into any other coding issues with your example:

```
TextBox2.Text = Rand(Long.Parse(TextBox1.Text), 100)
TextBox3.Text = Rand(Long.Parse(TextBox2.Text), 100)
' ... etc.
```

The `100` is based off your code, you may have some algorithm for setting the next higher range other than set values. If your first random number is `100` then the rest of your calculations are going to be non-random!

Comment: easy enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of the text boxes you want to fill at the form level.

```
Private lstTextBoxes As List(Of TextBox)
```

Fill the list in the Form.Load

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lstTextBoxes = New List(Of TextBox) From {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3}
End Sub
```

Use the .net Random class. It is easier than the old one.

```
Private Rand As New Random
```

Now you can loop through your text boxes and fill with a "random" number. Each iteration will be a higher number than the last but will stop when it reaches 100.

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim highNumber As Integer
        For Each txtBox As TextBox In lstTextBoxes
            If highNumber >= 99 Then
                Return
            End If
            highNumber = Rand.Next(highNumber + 1, 100)
            txtBox.Text = highNumber.ToString
        Next
 End Sub
```